# Implement interface by taking superclass of parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Why is this code (`ImplementingClass`) not valid?

What the are the issues that prevent this from being supported? Shouldn't a subclass (`InterfaceD`) be able to take in more than the superclass (`InterfaceC`), and use the same method? When something of type `InterfaceD` is used as type `InterfaceC`, all inputs will be handled fine. But `InterfaceD` would be able to handle other scenarios (objects of `ClassA`) too instead of just some (`ClassB`).

I know I can just implement both methods on `ImplementingClass` and pass off the call to the `InterfaceD` method, but why does the compiler demand that?

```
public class ClassA 
{
    // ...
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    // ...
}

public interface InterfaceC 
{
    void MethodA(ClassB)
}

public interface InterfaceD : InterfaceC 
{
    void MethodA(ClassA);
}

public class ImplementingClass : InterfaceD {
    void MethodA(ClassA)
    {
        // ...
    }
    // refuse to implement MethodA(ClassB) ...
}
```

Edit: A simpler example might be if `InterfaceD` did not exist, and I tried to just implement `InterfaceC` with the `MethodA(ClassA)`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Why java? It is tagged as C#!

Comment: Do you have a concrete example for your classes and interfaces? Making a case with letters is fine, but many times it only leads to made-up situations that you will not encounter.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `MethodA(ClassB)` because `InterfaceD` inherits from `InterfaceC` therefore `InterfaceD` now has `MethodA(ClassB)` and `MethodA(ClassA)` just like you can access methods of `ClassA` through an instance of `ClassB`.

The best approach would be to not derive `InterfaceD` from `InterfaceC` and have `ImplementingClass` implement the interfaces that it requires. Without seeing a concrete example its hard to comment, but it basically would come down to the design of you interfaces.